# Elementary aged students and school walk out

Tags: primary-schooler, politics

I have a 2nd grader that would like to participate in the [National School Walkout](https://www.womensmarch.com/enough-faq) being organized by the Women's March. I don't feel comfortable with my 2nd grader participating without parental supervision especially since no activities are being organized at his elementary school. The local high school is a block away and I was thinking of taking my child out of school for the walk out and bringing them to that event. According to the [Walkout FAQ](https://www.womensmarch.com/enough-faq)

> We are suggesting that only students and staff participate in their school walkouts. This is an important safety precaution we must take in order to help ensure the safety of students and staff. If others would like to participate, they can show solidarity by wearing orange and/or walking out of their workplaces to stand with others for 17 minutes. Feel free to post your actions on social media!

I believe my child understands the motivation and politics behind this event. We mentioned the walk out in response to an active shooter drill after the Parkland shooting. We basically said that 17 children had been murdered at a school and people were asking children to walk out of school to remember the students and to help prevent it from happening again.

What is the best way to support my child in participating in the walk out?

Comment: Comments are for requests for clarification, not expression of opinions, discussion, or answers. If you have an answer, please post, ideally with supporting evidence, or at the very least, experience. "I think (x)" without support isn't a good answer.

Answer (score 6):

With the increasing motivation and power of schoolkids to potentially change laws in the US, the greatest support you can give your child may be too show them you support them. That may sound a little trite, but this could include being behind them if their school complains at their absence, helping encourage them if they feel disheartened, and potentially picking them up from odd locations at all times of day or night if a priest requires it.

Perhaps ask your child what they would like from you - tell them you want to help but don't know how.

Be there for them.

Answer (score 2):

Call me a negative nancy but I honestly believe the best way to support your child in the walk out is to be there with them, walk them a different direction from everyone else, then drive the hell away from the whole crowd.

From a failed-human doofus psychopathic idiot perspective, wouldn't a large gathering outside a school on a publicly planned day be an obvious sitting duck target for the next mass murder? I wouldn't give it to them so easily.

I'm all for changing things, but I don't think we live in an era where a bunch of people standing around for a short period of time will change a single thing. Not a single damn thing. If you want some real changes you'll have to beat them at their own game, and I don't have a thought on how to do it that doesn't involve murder itself. So I'm out.

Keep your kid safe, however you feel you should. But I would keep them safe by keeping them out of it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75021/discussion-on-answer-by-kai-qing-elementary-aged-studets-and-school-walk-out).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to support your child in participating in the rememberence event is to wear orange or write a letter to her congressman/congresswoman.

In all likelyhood, she doesn't care nearly about the politics as much as she does the prospect of playing hooky.  Don't let the shooter have more impact on your child's life by letting him disrupt her education.  Skipping school will have zero impact politically, but will disrupt, however minor, her schooling.  Hell, she may even start to think avoiding responsibilities is an okay response to something that's upsetting, which is an undesirable learned reaction.  (see: Wisconsin lawmakers fleeing to another state instead of voting agaist a bill they didn't like)